Cannot run generateKeyPair from @solana/web3.js@rc
I am trying to run the command const keyPair: CryptoKeyPair = await generateKeyPair() and I get the following error:
throw new SolanaError(SOLANA_ERROR__SUBTLE_CRYPTO__GENERATE_FUNCTION_UNIMPLEMENTED);
Steps to reproduce

I've created a new node js app
I've installed the following:

    "dependencies": {
        "@solana/web3.js": "^2.0.0-rc.0",
        "buffer": "^6.0.3",
        "chalk": "4.1.2",
        "decimal.js": "^10.4.3",
        "dotenv": "^16.4.5",
        "viem": "^2.20.1"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@types/bn.js": "^5.1.0",
        "@types/chai": "^4.3.0",
        "@types/mocha": "^9.0.0",
        "chai": "^4.3.4",
        "mocha": "^9.0.3",
        "prettier": "^2.6.2",
        "ts-mocha": "^10.0.0",
        "ts-node": "^10.9.1",
        "tsconfig-paths": "^4.1.2",
        "typescript": "^5.5.4"
    }


and then I have a simple file (in index.ts)

;(async() => {
  const keyPair: CryptoKeyPair = await generateKeyPair();
})()

Here are a few more details from the error:
/Users/mehrancastle/Desktop/dev/personal/controller-lite/node_modules/@solana/assertions/src/subtle-crypto.ts:49
        throw new SolanaError(SOLANA_ERROR__SUBTLE_CRYPTO__GENERATE_FUNCTION_UNIMPLEMENTED);
              ^
SolanaError: No key generation implementation could be found.
    at Object.assertKeyGenerationIsAvailable (/Users/mehrancastle/Desktop/dev/personal/controller-lite/node_modules/@solana/assertions/src/subtle-crypto.ts:49:15)
    at generateKeyPair (/Users/mehrancastle/Desktop/dev/personal/controller-lite/node_modules/@solana/keys/src/key-pair.ts:14:11)
    at /Users/mehrancastle/Desktop/dev/personal/controller-lite/lib/controller/raw/index.ts:105:54
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/mehrancastle/Desktop/dev/personal/controller-lite/lib/controller/raw/index.ts:130:3)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1256:14)
    at Module.m._compile (/Users/mehrancastle/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:1618:23)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1310:10)
    at Object.require.extensions.<computed> [as .ts] (/Users/mehrancastle/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:1621:12)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1119:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:960:12) {
  cause: undefined,
  context: { __code: 3610004 }
}


Which version of Node are you running?

The error you're seeing, SolanaError: No key generation implementation could be found, points to the fact that the underlying cryptographic function (generateKeyPair) relies on the SubtleCrypto API, which is natively available in browser environments but not in Node.js without polyfills.
The current release candidate (RC) of @solana/web3.js (v2.0.0-rc.0) might be expecting this functionality to be available, but Node.js does not natively support all SubtleCrypto operations like key pair generation. This discrepancy triggers the error you're seeing.
Potential Solutions
Use Node.js Crypto Module: You can use Node.js's crypto module instead of SubtleCrypto. This requires modifying your approach to key generation. Here’s an example of using crypto.generateKeyPair in Node.js
import { generateKeyPair } from 'crypto';

(async () => {
  const { publicKey, privateKey } = generateKeyPair('rsa', {
    modulusLength: 2048,
    publicKeyEncoding: { type: 'spki', format: 'pem' },
    privateKeyEncoding: { type: 'pkcs8', format: 'pem' },
  }, (err, pubKey, privKey) => {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log('Public Key:', pubKey);
    console.log('Private Key:', privKey);
  });
})();

Since @solana/web3.js@rc relies on WebCrypto APIs that aren't natively available in Node.js, the ideal solution is to polyfill the SubtleCrypto API using @peculiar/webcrypto, which provides WebCrypto functionality in Node.js.
You need to inject the polyfill into the global context to simulate browser-like crypto support in Node.js.
import { Crypto } from '@peculiar/webcrypto';
import { generateKeyPair } from '@solana/web3.js'; // Ensure you're importing correctly

// Polyfill SubtleCrypto in Node.js
global.crypto = new Crypto();

(async () => {
  try {
    // Use the generateKeyPair method from @solana/web3.js@rc
    const keyPair: CryptoKeyPair = await generateKeyPair();
    console.log('KeyPair generated successfully:', keyPair);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error generating key pair:', error);
  }
})();

This polyfill will allow your Node.js environment to handle WebCrypto operations like key pair generation.
The generateKeyPair function should now work as expected since SubtleCrypto is now available in the global context.
